# Reverse OR Algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, hex, logical-operators

Let me first describe my situation.

I have a list of Hex values, which are called BaseID. They are chosen **such that logical OR between any number of them will give you a unique ID** which is called FinalID. That is, my BaseID values are as follows.

BaseID = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, ... }

The critical point is that I don't know how many BaseIDs that I will have **before I run the program** (I do get a list of BaseIDs once I run the program as it is read from a file), or **how many out of the total number of the BaseIDs will be used to create the FinalID**. It is decided based upon other parts of my program. For example, following are two FinalIDs that I might have in my program.

FinalID = ( 0x01 | 0x04 ) = 0x05

FinalID = ( 0x02 | 0x04 | 0x10 ) = 0x16

Now, using OR operation for any number of BaseIDs is the easy part. My problem is, I need to extract from FinalID the BaseIDs used to create that FinalID. Since I've chosen BaseIDs such that they, once the OR operation is used, will ALWAYS give me a unique FinalID, I know that any given FinalID is created using a specific set of BaseIDs. Note that a FinalID can be created using only one BaseID too which is the equivalent of FinalID = ( BaseID | 0x00 ).

I know what I have to do to extract the BaseIDs used to create any particular FinalID; I have to get the complete list of BaseIDs involved, then use OR operator among each and every comibnation of elements to find out if which combination gives the particular FinalID.

However I'm finding it hard to convert this logic into a program. I am using C# with .NET 3.5 Framework. Any suggestions/ideas would be very much appreciated. A code sample is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so you've got a bitmask... all you need to do is "AND" your FinalID with each possible BaseID - if the result is non-zero, that BaseID contributed to the FinalID:

```
// Or just go from 0... count and use 1 << x
foreach (int baseId in BaseIDs)
{
    if ((baseId & finalId) != 0)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would also suggest that you might want to use a "flags" enum for this, which will make your life simpler in terms of language integration.

Comment: I was writing exactly the same. You were faster :\

Comment: If you have `0x07` and `0x0F`, did they both contribute? Or did only `0x0F`? How would you determine contribution when they both overlap? How about when it's not a complete subset, such as `0x06` and `0x07`?

Comment: @glowcoder: 0x0F isn't a valid BaseId. 0x06 is a combination of 0x02 and 0x04, and 0x07 is a combination of 0x01, 0x02 and 0x04.

Comment: @Jon I suppose the `...` in the `BaseID` array declaration does imply a pattern. It didn't seem apparent from the question that it was limited to powers of two, just that the only values he provided (which comprise a small subset of potential numbers) happened to be; I would hate to think that I say `0x10` and thought to myself it wasn't a power of 2... :) Well then yes, for strictly powers of two this is what to do!

Comment: @glowcoder: Well, the OP did specify "They are chosen such that logical OR between any number of them will give you a unique ID" - that pretty much implies they're powers of 2...

Comment: @Jon I suppose I consider powers of two to be a special case of that property in which no bits happen to overlap. Consider `a=001101` `b=010101` and `c=001010`. There are three potential ors, with `ab=011101` `ac=001111` and `bc=011111`. Granted, I haven't analyzed this to determine if it is scalable, and something inside tells me that you will never be able to reach the number of digits in the structure like bitmasking can.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the late reply. Yes, what @glowcoder says is right; BaseIDs ARE powers of 2.

Comment: Oh and I did get the problems solved with this answer, thank you very much everyone who contributed!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my suggestion:

```
        uint mask = 0x1;

        do
        {
            if ((finalId & mask) == mask)
            {
                // Base-ID found
            }
            mask <<= 1;
        }
        while (mask < finalId);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var baseId = new int[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10 };
var finalId = 0x01|0x02|0x10;

foreach (var b in baseId)
{
    if ((finalId & b) == b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

I'll add that using `int` you can have up to 32 baseId and using `long` you can have up to 64 baseId. Using the `BigInteger` class theorically you could go as high as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try...

```
foreach(Id baseID in baseIDs)
{
    if(baseID & finalID != 0)
        results.Add(candidate);
}
```

Should do nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the list of all BaseIDs, then doing an AND with FinalID should tell you whether it was used or not.

Logic

```
Assume allBaseIds are sorted from lower to higher
For each (var baseId in allBaseIds)
{
   // FinalId will always be greater then consisting baseIds
   if(finalId < baseId)
     break;

   // As each base id represents a different bit, so its AND should result in baseId itself.
   if((finalId AND baseId) == baseId)
   {
      // This base id was used to make this final id.
   }
   else
   {
     // this base id was not used to make this final id
   }
}
```